# Laravel doesn't fetch date/time from server

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I'm using laravel with xampp as it's server. But it doesn't seem to get the proper time. I tested this by having this code: `echo $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` on a page in "htdocs" (not laravel just plain php) and on a function inside a laravel controller. The "today.php" in htdocs work while the one in laravel doesn't.

Any idea where I can configure the date/time in my laravel application?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @CanVural no errors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I set Default time zone in controller, but this is tedious though since I have multiple controllers.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$today = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get current date and time by below changes:

Just need to change 'timezone' from `config/app.php`

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

**Or**

Set Default time zone in controller:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$today = new DateTime();
```

**Note:** Declare `use DateTime;` on top.

**EDIT:**

Laravel provide a unified API for various caching systems and this system store current configuration settings. So if make any change then you must need to clear configuration cache. You can clear the cache like below using artisan command:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this help you well!

Comment: Already did the change on config/app.php. But still it doesn't work. Though the solution on the controller works but is there any setting in laravel to make it universal on all controllers? 

But thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I hope you clear cache after above changes taken. If not done please check my EDIT

Comment: Already did clear cache..but still to no avail. The 2nd solution works though, the only problem is that I have to put it on every controller.

Answer (score 1):

you can set timezone in config/app.php

```
 'timezone' => 'UTC',
```